# How find all parameters for GridSearchCV in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to find full set of parameters per each estimator:

```
estimators = [df.svm.SVR(), df.svm.LinearSVR(), df.svm.NuSVR()]
```

In test code, I added only few details `'kernel':('linear', 'rbf')` that was found in example:

```
from sklearn import svm, grid_search, datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svr = svm.SVC()
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svr, parameters)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
...                             

> GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score=...,
>        estimator=SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=..., class_weight=..., coef0=...,
>                      decision_function_shape=None, degree=..., gamma=...,
>                      kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False,
>                      random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=...,
>                      verbose=False),
>        fit_params={}, iid=..., n_jobs=1,
>        param_grid=..., pre_dispatch=..., refit=...,
>        scoring=..., verbose=...)
```

What is the best way to find all possible parameters and their values?

Comment: You can use `svr.get_params()` to get a list of all parameters that GridSearchCV can tune. I'm not sure if it's possible to get a list of possible values (other than reading the docs).

Comment: The parameters you use will change on depending on the algorithm you are using. Random forests will have different parameters than K nearest neighbors and both of those will be different than support vector machines. The above comment shows ho to get the parameters for each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to read the docs (or at least docstrings through `help( )` command) of each method and decide which parameters to fit. In particular, many of them have infinite number of possible values (such as C) thus you cannot check **all** values. You will need some sampling.

In particular noone besides you can decide whether to check many ways of weighting samples in SVM or not, whether or not to test multiple stopping tolerance parameters or not.